# Get event log details into powershell script launched by scheduled task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, event-log

I'm a newbie in scripting, sorry for this. I need to get details from event log into a script launched by task scheduler triggered by this same event log but i dont know how.

Each event log have a unique EventRecordID that can identify a unique event.

Project example : auto creating/deleting exchange mail box when creating/deleting AD user

For this example, the microsoft security auditing have to be enabled.
Each instance of task will run a script. This script can't be based on EventID to retreive a new AD account, verify if a mailbox already exist and then create the mailbox. If many admins create at same time user account, task scheduler will launch the script many times and could crash or make errors. Thats why it's necessary to get details, into the task running script, about the event that triggered the task to retreive SAMAccountname, user SID or other. This details are available on event log details with EventID 4720(for new user account).

Someone can help me?

Thanks very much.

J.